# What are the implications of upgrading statistics SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I Have a SQL Server 2005 DB, with 500Gb of Data. The Statics do not upgrade from 2010 and this past saturday were updated. Yesterday the querys on DB were very slow and caused bad response times.

Nothing more change in the database since Saturday, so I think it may be the work in the statistics.

Tell me about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Tell me about it?

You are speculating. I recommend that instead you investigate. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/). Find the bottlenecks, address them appropriately, based on your findings. Measure before you cut.